# Can't call stored procedure without specifying supposedly optional parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I'm trying to call a stored procedure with several required and several optional parameters.  Before I came along, the beginning of the procedure scripted out like this:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetStudents]
(
    @SortOrder          varchar(50),
    @SortColumn         varchar(150),
    @SortLetter         varchar(10),
    @Status             varchar(250),
    @PageIndex              int,
    @PageSize           int,
    @User_ID            int,
    @Reference_No           varchar(50) = NULL,
    @First_Name         varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Middle_Name            varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Last_Name          varchar(50) = NULL
)
As
BEGIN
-- other stuff here
```

Everything seems to work fine. Then I added another parameter to the end:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetStudents]
(
    @SortOrder          varchar(50),
    @SortColumn         varchar(150),
    @SortLetter         varchar(10),
    @Status             varchar(250),
    @PageIndex              int,
    @PageSize           int,
    @User_ID            int,
    @Reference_No           varchar(50) = NULL,
    @First_Name         varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Middle_Name            varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Last_Name          varchar(50) = NULL,
    @ContextID          int = NULL
)
As
BEGIN
-- other stuff here
```

and now it's broken.  When I use ADO.NET to call the stored proc by setting up a command object with parameters, it throws an exception because I'm not setting the `@ContextID` parameter.

Any idea why?  I thought if I set it to the default value of `NULL`, then it would effectually be totally optional.

*Update*: here's how the SqlCommand gets set up, as best I can represent it here:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetStudents");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@SortOrder";
param.Value = sortOrder;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
param2.ParameterName = "@SortColumn";
param2.Value = sortColumn;
param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortLetter", sortLetter));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", status));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PageIndex", pageIndex));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PageSize", pageSize));

// here, the code splits a search expression into multiple parameters, looping over a switch statement like this:

foreach (string token in tokens)
{
    switch(token)
    {
        case "Reference_No":
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Reference_No", (object)value ?? DBNull.Value));
            break;
        case "First_Name":
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@First_Name", (object)value ?? DBNull.Value));
            break;
        case "Last_Name":
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Last_Name", (object)value ?? DBNull.Value));
            break;
        case "Middle_Name":
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Middle_Name", (object)value ?? DBNull.Value));
            break;
        case "Generation":
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Generation", (object)value ?? DBNull.Value));
            break;
        case "ContextID":
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContextID", (object)value ?? DBNull.Value));
            break;
    }
}

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", userID);
// fires off cmd through a DAL
```

Here's the exception (of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`):

> The parameterized query '(@Reference_No varchar(50),
>                                         @First_Name varchar(5' expects the parameter '@ContextID', which was not supplied.

I find this message kind of odd because the formatting seems jacked.  Anyway, under the hood the command gets executed via a `SqlDataAdapter` which is used to fill a `DataSet`.  The exception is thrown during the `Fill` method execution.

Comment: What does the code for your ADO call look like?

Comment: have you checked the exception as well?

Comment: @DeveloperJigarPandya what do you mean by "checked"?  As in, inspected the message and stack trace, or do you mean something programmatic?

Comment: I might have missed it, but what's the exact exception you get?

Comment: Yes I want to know the exact exception.. sorry for miss leading..

Comment: @DeveloperJigarPandya following?  You mean stepping into it with the debugger?

Comment: @BenCollins Have you try the following answer?

Comment: @DeveloperJigarPandya the answer below is technically correct, although MSDN examples don't use this keyword in this way.  It didn't make a difference in my case, though.

Comment: I think what happened is that the parameter was being used somewhere down in the guts of the sproc where it was assumed to have a value.  When I tried running the sproc directly in SSMS, it showed exactly where it bombed and it wasn't at the top.  It was way down i th emiddle.

Comment: Can you select `@@version` and post back the exact version/build?

Answer (score 0):

On this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx link following line is mentioned..

> The value of each declared parameter must be supplied by the user when the procedure is called unless a default value for the parameter is defined or the value is set to equal another parameter. If a procedure contains table-valued parameters, and the parameter is missing in the call, an empty table is passed in.

So based on that I can say that if you put the "Default" Key work your problem will be resolved.

Also on the same page information regarding default is mention with details like following.

> default
>   A default value for a parameter. If a default value is defined for a parameter, the procedure can be executed without specifying a value for that parameter. The default value must be a constant or it can be NULL. The constant value can be in the form of a wildcard, making it possible to use the LIKE keyword when passing the parameter into the procedure. See Example C below.
>
> Default values are recorded in the sys.parameters.default column only
>   for CLR procedures. That column will be NULL for Transact-SQL
>   procedure parameters.

Thanks,
Jigar